# How to create a quarterly (fiscal year) temp table in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I'm working with a large medical claims dataset that spans over 3 years (in Hive). I want to break each year up into quarters, based on one of the column values, `date_service`

Here's roughly what I've done:

```
create table user.temp_quarterly as
select *, 
    CASE WHEN date_service between '2015-10-01' and '2015-12-31' THEN 'Q1 2016'
    WHEN date_service between '2016-01-01' and '2016-03-31' THEN 'Q2 2016'
    WHEN date_service between '2016-04-01' and '2016-06-30' THEN 'Q3 2016'
    WHEN date_service between '2016-07-01' and '2016-09-30' THEN 'Q4 2016'

    WHEN date_service between '2016-10-01' and '2016-12-31' THEN 'Q1 2017'
    WHEN date_service between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-31' THEN 'Q2 2017'
    WHEN date_service between '2017-04-01' and '2017-06-30' THEN 'Q3 2017'
    WHEN date_service between '2017-07-01' and '2017-09-30' THEN 'Q4 2017'

    WHEN date_service between '2017-10-01' and '2017-12-31' THEN 'Q1 2018'
    WHEN date_service between '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-31' THEN 'Q2 2018'
    WHEN date_service between '2018-04-01' and '2018-06-30' THEN 'Q3 2018'
    WHEN date_service between '2018-07-01' and '2018-09-30' THEN 'Q4 2018'

    ELSE null END AS Quarter
from user.temp_medicalclaims
```

Is this the right approach or is there a more efficient way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler to do:

```
select ('Q' || quarter(add_months(date_service, 3)) || 'Q' ||
        year(add_months(date_service, 3))
       ) as yyyyq
```

That is, add three months and use the built-in functions for year and quarter.